# Extracting information from database using JSON and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I'm trying to make a simple "search" box using Javascript, AJAX, php and JSON. For this project, I'm just using the database "world" I downloaded from mqsql website.
I'm running into a problem when trying to extract the information from my database. It just takes the first line of information and then I get this 
error: "SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Continent' of undefined or null reference
ajaj.js (65,3)"

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to give me!

Here is my ajaj.js code:

```
var ajaxRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
var input;
var button;

function init(){
    input = document.getElementById('search');
    input.addEventListener("keyup", sendRequest, false);
    button = document.getElementById('sendButton');
    button.addEventListener("click", sendSecondRequest, false);
}


function sendRequest(){
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = getRequest;

    var searchTxt = "country=" + input.value;

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "getCountries.php?" + searchTxt, true);
    ajaxRequest.send();
}


function getRequest(){
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState==4 && ajaxRequest.status==200){
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);

        var dataList = document.getElementById('countries');

        dataList.innerHTML="";

        for(var i = 0; i<jsonObj.length; i++){

            var option = document.createElement('option');

            option.value = jsonObj[i]['Name'];

            dataList.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
}

function sendSecondRequest(){
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = getSecondRequest;

    var infoCountry = "country=" + input.value;

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "getCountries2.php?" + infoCountry, true);
    ajaxRequest.send();
}

function getSecondRequest(){
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState==4 && ajaxRequest.status==200){
        alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
        var jsonObj2 = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);




        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "LANDSKOD: " + jsonObj2[0]["Code"] + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "LANDSKOD: " + jsonObj2[2]["Continent"] + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = "LANDSKOD: " + jsonObj2[7]["Population"] + "<br>";

    }
}

window.addEventListener("load",init,false);
```

It's here where the problem lies, I just don't know how to get it to work:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "LANDSKOD: " + jsonObj2[0]["Code"] + "<br>";
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "LANDSKOD: " + jsonObj2[2]["Continent"] + "<br>";
document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = "LANDSKOD: " + jsonObj2[7]["Population"] + "<br>";
```

I've tried a few different solutions but I can't get it working, I've tried to combine the code into one line using:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "LANDSKOD: " + jsonObj2[0]["Code"] + "<br>" + "Continent: " + jsonObj2[2]["Continent] + "<br>";
```

but that doesn't seem to work for me either.

Rest of my code:

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AJAX</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaj.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sök information om ett land</h1>

<input type="text" list="countries"  id = 'search' placeholder="Land">
<datalist id="countries">
</datalist>
<button type="button" id="sendButton">Hämta information</button>

<p id="result"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
<p id="result3"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

getCountries.php

```
<?php
include_once('db.inc.php');

$country = $_GET['country'];

// Kör frågan mot databasen world och tabellen country
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM country WHERE Name Like ? ORDER BY Name");
$stmt->execute(array("$country%"));

$tableRows = array();

// Lägger resultatet i vår array
$tableRows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Här konverteras och skickas resultatet i JSON-format
echo json_encode($tableRows);
?>
```

getCountries2.php

```
<?php
include_once('db.inc.php');

$country = $_GET['country'];

// Kör frågan mot databasen world och tabellen country
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM country WHERE Name Like ? ORDER BY Name");
$stmt->execute(array("$country"));

$tableRows = array();

// Lägger resultatet i vår array
$tableRows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Här konverteras och skickas resultatet i JSON-format
echo json_encode($tableRows);
?>
```

db.inc.php

```
<?php

define ('DB_USER', 'root');
define ('DB_PASSWORD', 'Abc12345');
define ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define ('DB_NAME', 'world');

$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8';
$db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
?>
```

EDIT: I just got the answer from the comments, the information is on the same row, not different, therefore it didn't work with

```
jsonObj2[2]["Continent"]
```

but it did work with

```
jsonObj2[0]["Continent"]
```

Thank you @sean!

Comment: Are you sure your Continent column is named Continent in your database (with C and not c)? Instead of `SELECT * FROM ...` try to get your data one by one maybe to be sure.

Comment: @MickaelLeger Yes I am sure, this is the JSON response I get from the server/database https://gyazo.com/3be9699ea6fc2477c174803ac86a6a59

Comment: Are you sure you want the 3rd Row value - `jsonObj2[2]...` and not the 1st Row value - `jsonObj2[0]["Continent"]`? I think you are confusing Row vs Column.

Comment: I think Sean is right, the JSON response you get contain ONE Obj with different key, so you want to find jsonObj2[0]["Continent]`, same for `jsonObj2[7]["Population"]` I think -> `jsonObj2[0]["Population"]`

Comment: @Sean You are correct, I actually thought each piece of information was on it's on row, It's actually just on the same row, using jsonObj2[0]["continent"] worked excellent! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that jsonObj2[2] isnt object. It seems like you dont have 3 rows (jsonObj2[2]) in database return array. 
Try

```
jsonObj2[0]["Code"] + jsonObj2[0]["Continent"] + sonObj2[0] 
["Population"]
```

It should work but dont know why you target to rows 0,2,7.

Comment: I was just confused about Row vs Column, I thought each piece of information were on their own row. Thank you for your help!